# Using handlebars.js in the browser. How? requirejs? commonjs? amd? babel? what?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating

I want to use Handlebars library in the browser.

no require, no babel, no ES2015. Just plain old javascript so it works.

I tried insatlling handlebars via npm, then using gulp to babel or amd or requriejs or something but it's not working.

Is there even avaialble a plain javascript working version of Handlebars?

Alternatively a different templating engine. I just need it for a simple HTML5 project.

Sorry but why is this so hard, it should be easy! keep it simple stupid! aargh!

Comment: How about just a script tag that pulls the library from cdnjs?: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js

Comment: I just put that in a new <scritp> tag and it worked! :O thanks

I tried downloading the source and putting it into my gulp. Turns out the problem was I was running it through gulp-babel and that messed it up somehow.

Freakin front end dev these days .. info overload! haha xD